# Found nil when trying to add records to sqlite Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I create my table with the following:

```
  let db = try Connection("\(path)/db.sqlite3")   

        let users = Table("users")
        let assetTag = Expression<String?>("asset_tag")
        let location = Expression<String?>("location")


        try db.run(users.create { t in
            t.column(assetTag)
            t.column(location)
```

I am then adding records to both columns with the following:

```
 for tag in tags

        {
            try db.run(users.insert(assetTag <- tag))

        }

        for locale in locations
        {
            try db.run(users.insert(location <- locale))

        }
```

and then I select the values and try to print them with this:

```
 for user in try db.prepare(users.select(assetTag)) {
                    tagArray.append(user[assetTag])
            }

            for user in try db.prepare(users.select(location)) {
                locationArray.append(user[location])
            }

            print (tagArray)
            print (locationArray)
```

For some reason I am getting an error stating there is a nil value somewhere but I am not sure where the nil is coming from. Also note I removed the catch statements to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found that having two insert statements was not inserting my records correctly and inserting nulls. The below code is how to insert two arrays at the same time into the database to prevent nulls:

```
for (locale, tag) in zip(locations, tags)

        {
            try db.run(users.insert(assetTag <- tag, location <- locale))

        }
```